# Escaping forward slash ("/") while using JavaScript to change CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add some CSS class based on some condition using JavaScript but facing issue in case my string contains a forward slash (`/`). This is what my use case is

```
<div id="div_product-size-icon-121NM/L" class="disabled"></div>
<script>
var newProductCode = '121NM/L';
 if(  newProductCode.contains('/') ){
       newProductCode = newProductCode.replace('/','/\//');
       $('#'+'div_product-size-icon-'+newProductCode).addClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

I have even tried  `newProductCode.replace('/','/\');` but while running code, I am facing following error

> JavaScript error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

I can not change HTML along with product code; the option for me is to change it in JS.

Here is a working js example: [JS code](http://js.do/code/90166)

Comment: What do you expect `newProductCode` to be after replacing?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ... so there is a slash in your newProductCode which you want to replace with????? what?

Comment: @devnull69: I have a `div` and want to add some class in case it meets my condition, in case I do not use it `$('#'+'div_product-size-icon-'+newProductCode)` will throw error when js code will run

Comment: So like just like this: `$('#div_product-size-icon-'+newProductCode.replace('/','\\/')).addClass('myNewClass')`???  http://js.do/code/90167

Comment: @Wolff : This is just awesome..I need to try on my running code but it seems to be working. Can you put it as an answer plz

Comment: Look at this link http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have first replaced the if statement with `indexOf()` and changed the `.replace` function as `.replace('/', '\\/');`

```js
var newProductCode = '121NM/L';
if (newProductCode.indexOf('/') > 0) {
  alert('Once you click OK, the text will disappear!!');
  newProductCode = newProductCode.replace('/', '\\/');
  $('#' + 'div_product-size-icon-' + newProductCode).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
div.active {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_product-size-icon-121NM/L" class="disabled">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: What if you want to replace all /?  What I have found (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) is, for example, use string.replace( /blue/g, 'red') to replace all instances of blue with red. But if I want to escape / to replace all of them, I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: newProductCode =  newProductCode.replace(/\//g, "@");   this would replace all '/' occurance with '@' as an example

Answer (score 1):

@Pugazh probably has the correct way of doing it, but you could just isolate the `string` in `"` by searching using an `attribute` in jQuery. Here's a [link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to the API documentation. It avoids having to do the replace altogether. It's a hacky way of doing it.

```
var newProductCode = '121NM/L';
$('[id="div_product-size-icon-'+newProductCode+'"]').addClass('active');
```