# Escaping a forward slash / for variable in Ajax URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with existing code which validates a user's submission by sending to a given URL via Ajax:

```
var url = '/foo/bar/' + valuea + '/' + valueb + '/' + valuec;
```

Which is then sent via ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url  : url,
    // data : data,
    success :  function(response)
    {...
    }
 });
```

The issue lies when the user input contains a forward slash e.g.:

`valuec = ABC/DEF`

As then the url becomes defined as:

`/far/bar/{valuea}/{valueb}/ABC/DEF`

Which results in a whole different URL structure and 404s.

Is there a way I can escape this value to maintain the required URL structure?

I've tried the likes of `replace(/\//, '\/');` and also `encodeURIComponent()` but neither help.

My current thinking is a workaround to rewrite any '/' in the user submitted data to something else (e.g. |) so I can parse it to the URL, and then re-adjust it upon return, but that's a bit of a messy workaround imho.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469397/escaping-forward-slash-while-using-javascript-to-change-css-class/36469774 or replace('/', '&#47;')?

Answer (score 4):

`encodeURIComponent` will work.[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3x9z4/246/)

```js
valuea = 1;
valueb = 2;
valuec = "ABC/DEF";
var url = '/foo/bar/' + valuea + '/' + valueb + '/' + encodeURIComponent(valuec); 
document.write(url+'<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values as query string parameters

```
var url = "/foo/bar/?valuea=" + valuea + "&valueb=" + valueb + "&valuec=" + valuec;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies. Unfortunately due to prebuilt limitations I cannot amend the URL structure, and the encodeURIComponent doesn't work in:

```
    $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url  : url,
```

So, instead I've gone for the replace method...!

```
    valuec = valuec.replace(/\//g, '|||');
```

So it parses to the API correctly, and then at that end, I swap them back.

Cheers